# Does a Tool for Automatically Visualizing a Project's Source Code's Control Flow In-Line Exist?

Tags: static-analysis, documentation-generation, code-documentation, code-visualization

I would like to be able to use a tool that lets you visualize a program's control flow(s) in the context of its source code.  To clarify, such a tool should basically show what happens in a program by spitting out a human-readable abstract syntax tree in the form of a [multidigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(mathematics)) with nodes containing snippets of source-code translation units.  The resulting graph initial node would, I presume, contain the block of code starting with a program's entry point (that'd be `main` for a C or C++ program.)  New nodes would be created when a node needs to reference another block of code, whether that might be in the current file or in another one, and arrows would connect the nodes.  Does such a tool exist, or would it have to be created from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to get a tool that does this for arbitrary languages off the shelf.  There are too many languages, each with its own syntax and semantics.  You somehow need a tool per language.  You might find such tools for very commonly used languages, e.g, [Understand for Software](http://scitools.com/).

I think that the only way to do this is to build metatools that enable the construction of language-specific tools relatively easily.  Such a tool has to have the common machinery needed by all such language processing tools: strong parsers (so writing grammars for languages is relatively straightforward), AST construction machinery,  symbol table support,  routines to build control and data flow graphs.  By providing such machinery, one can build language front ends for modest costs.

There's a class of tools that does this, [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  Most of them have parsing engines, but not the rest of the mechanisms I have suggested above.

I believe this enough to have invested 20 years of my life to building
such meta tools. Our [DMS Software Reengineering toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) shows its strength in being able to parse some [50+ languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/index.html?Home=DMSToolkit), including the stunningly hard C++14 (both MS and GNU variants).   It shows symbol table support and [control flow graph construction](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) for COBOL, Java, C, C++.  (We can't do everything at once; pedaling as fast as practical). 
[DMS builds these graphs as data structures rather than "showing" them; the examples on that page are drawn with the additional help of DOT].

One of the few other tools that tries to do this is [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/); this covers a wide variety of popular languages.  Clang doesn't have any specific support for parsing that I know about; you get to code it all yourself.   I think you get control flow graphs only after you convert the language to LLVM.   I don't think it has any specific support for drawing control flow graphs, either.

An older tool with a good reputation for multi-language support in this space is [CoCo/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/);
I don't know a lot about it.  I know it parses,
and has some support for ASTs; I don't know what it does
about control flow analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the many useful pointers!  I will look into each of them in turn.